# json-rpc of bitcoin not working for testnet(curl command)

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-core-development

I am trying this command to get transaction from bitcoin testnet:

```
curl  --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "gettransaction", "params": ["txId"] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://username:password@IP:PORT/
```

And i am getting following error

```
{ "result":null, "error":{"code" :-32601, "message" : "Method not found"}, id:curltext}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your core compiled with the wallet? Because `gettransaction` RPC get wallet transactions, and hence need wallet capabilities. For general transactions, you should use `getrawtransaction` instead.
I ran it here (with wallet enabled) and works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing invalid `transaction` to the `gettransaction` method.

Comment: no that's not the case. I am passing a valid txId.