# Bitcoin-cli responding but not curl

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, api, bitcoin-cli

According to the [bitcoin documentation](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getbestblockhash.html) I can make `curl` calls to my bitcoin node. However, whenever I run a curl command like the following (as per the docs):

```
curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "getbestblockhash", "params": []}' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

I get no response. But when I run the `bitcoin-cli` edition:

```
bitcoin-cli getbestblockhash
```

I get a response.

So what is the difference? What am I missing?

I've seen [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84464/bitcoin-curl-no-reply) and [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83165/json-rpc-of-bitcoin-not-working-for-testnetcurl-command) but they were never resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it out, you just need to give it a username and password. You can add them to a `bitcoin.conf` file in your datadir. This file isn't automatically created. The default datadir is at `~/.bitcoin`, so you can make a `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

```
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pass
```

---

Additionally, if you'd like, you can later pass your username and passwords as URL parameters, like so:

```
http://user:password@IP_ADDRESS:PORT
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the configuration file **is not automatically** created; you can create it using your favorite text editor. By default, the configuration file name is `bitcoin.conf` and it is located in the Bitcoin data directory, but both the Bitcoin data directory and the configuration file path may be changed using the `-datadir` and `-conf` command-line options. Also, do not forget to set the appropriate file permissions and restart the `bitcoind`.